# C Linked List Skipping First 3 Lines

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am working on an insert_node function to add nodes to a linked list. The structure for nodes looks like this:

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function produces a memory leak

```
prior_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

This while loop

```
while(newNodePtr->grocery_item.stockNumber > traversePtr->grocery_item.stockNumber && traversePtr->next != NULL) {

        prior_node = traversePtr;
        traversePtr = traversePtr->next;

    }
```

can invoke undefined behavior because there is no check whether the current value of the pointer `traversePtr` is equal to NULL.

The function can be defined simpler the following way.

```
void insert_node( Node **list_head_ptr, Node *newNodePtr ) 
{
    while ( *list_head_ptr != NULL && 
            !( newNodePtr->grocery_item.stockNumber < (*list_head_ptr)->grocery_item.stockNumber ) )
    {
        list_head_ptr = &( *list_head_ptr )->next;
    }

    newNodePtr->next = *list_head_ptr;
    *list_head_ptr = newNodePtr;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. Probably want to reference an explanation of iterating with the address of the pointer to keep the OP's head from exploding. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: How could I fix my code while keeping the if-else-else structure?

Comment: @ABC It is not a good approach. to use if-else statements. You could set prior_node  equal to *list_head_ptr.